# Spring Data Access Exception when SQL string gets 'SYSDATE' passed as a String param

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring

**PROBLEM BACKGROUND**

I'm trying to insert a record into my database using the spring framework. As part of this process I've created an SQL string (see below) in my DAO class which takes some parameters and inserts them into the query string I've declared as a field. 
There are two fields in my database which are set to the current date if certain conditions are selected by the user of the front end (suspended/ disabled).

The issue is that Spring doesn't allow me to inject the String `SYSDATE` as a parameter into my query, it expects it to be a numeric type because the column in my database is a `DATE` type.

Instead of creating 4 separate SQL strings to accommodate the four possible selections made by the user (not disabled/suspended, suspended, disabled, disabled AND suspended) I'd prefer to just have the one statement that inserts the value `SYSDATE` into the SQL string depending on the value being passed to the calling method.

**SQL STRING**

- doesn't work

  ```
  private int myMethod(...) {
      int created = 0;
      created = super.getJdbcTemplate().update(createNewObject,
      new Object[] {1, "t-1000", "good", "SYSDATE", "SYSDATE"});
      return created;}
  ```

(the method above actually takes variables of those data types displayed in the update method of the JdbcTemplate but just to give you a rough idea of the parameters I'm passing)

```
    private final static String createNewObject = "INSERT INTO my_table"
                + "(ID, \"MODEL\", STATUS, OVERRIDE, DISABLED) " 
                + "VALUES "
                + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

`Caused By: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`

- works

  ```
  private final static String createNewObject = "INSERT INTO my_table"
              + "(ID, \"MODEL\", STATUS, OVERRIDE, DISABLED) " 
              + "VALUES "
              + "(?, ?, ?, SYSDATE, SYSDATE)";
  ```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can make this single-query approach work as opposed to having separate query's for each possible condition selected by the user.

Comment: Try new Object[] {1, "t-1000", "good", new Date(), new Date() }; instead of new Object[] {1, "t-1000", "good", "SYSDATE", "SYSDATE"});

Comment: yeah that solved the problem thanks very much! If you could post that as an answer so that I could accept it as the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `new Object[] {1, "t-1000", "good", new Date(), new Date() };` instead of `new Object[] {1, "t-1000", "good", "SYSDATE", "SYSDATE"});`